# Incremented CharField

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

is there any possibility to define a Field which gets incremented, but starts with a letter? So the values should be like: S123, S124, S125.

I' d like to use the id field for it, but some reason i' d like to have it as a CharField.

As a workaround i could use:

```
id = models.CharField(max_length = 32, primary_key = True)
```

and redefine the save method, so i always precalculate its value, but this won' t be that robust than a "real" solution, and also my solution would too slow with the calculation.

Is there a proper solution for my problem?

Django: 1.9.2
Python: 3.4.2

.

Comment: This might be of interest for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should manually define a primary key. Django usually uses relational database to build an app, which means it would rely on some key field to `join` other tables to do the lookup when it needs to. Having primary keys like `S123` makes it extra hard to maintain because you need to store the same thing as a reference in other tables.

What I would suggest is storing the letter part and the digits separately. You could use the default `id` field django created as the digit part and create your own field to store the letter part. Then you would use a property method to return the value you want to have. Roughly:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    letter = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    @property
    def symbol(self):
        return '%s%s' % (self.letter, self.id)
```

Then you could do:

```
foo = Foo.objects.create(letter='S')
print foo.symbol   # this would print S1, S2, etc.
```

In case you don't know, here's an explanation of [@property in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work).

Comment: Well, as a final solution i added a new field (c_id, CharField), and i maintain its value during the post_save signal (when it' s created).